# How do I use a recordset in vba and add it to a SQL select query?

Tags: sql, vba, oracle, netezza, recordset

I am trying to get VBA to run a select query in a netezza database and then insert the results from that into a table in an Oracle database table.

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub Netezza_to_Oracle_table()

Dim mcon As ADODB.Connection
Dim mConnectionString As String
Dim mrecset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim mSqlQry As String

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim recset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SqlQry As String

Set mcon = New ADODB.Connection
Set mrecset = New ADODB.Recordset
    
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset
    
mConnectionString = "dsn=NZSQL;servername=servername;port=1234;database=database;User ID=me01;password=password123"
ConnectionString = "GOODSQL.1;User ID=cheese_data;password=password456;Data Source=ORACLE"

mcon.Open mConnectionString

mSqlQry = "SELECT COLUMNS FROM TABLE WHERE ETC "

mrecset.Open mSqlQry, mcon
 
con.Open ConnectionString
    
SqlQry = " INSERT INTO MY_ORACLE_TABLE (SELECT * FROM " & ("mrecset") & " ) "

recset.Open SqlQry, con

recset.Close

mcon.Close
Set mrecset = Nothing 

con.Close
Set recset = Nothing  
  
End Sub
```

The problem I think I have is getting the recordset from

```
mrecset.Open mSqlQry, mcon
```

into

```
SqlQry = " INSERT INTO MY_ORACLE_TABLE (SELECT * FROM " & ("mrecset") & " ) "
```

As there is a message saying the table does not exist when it gets to

```
recset.Open SqlQry, con,
```

If I replace the SQL in `SqlQry` with

```
select * from MY_ORACLE_TABLE
```

then it runs that code.

Am I doing this all wrong or is there something relatively simple I can add/change to get it to work? (Or can I somehow create a virtual temp table and refer to that?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears it can't be done like this with VBA.  I'm going to export the netezza dataset (copyfromrecordset) to excel and then use a sql loader to import the data to the oracle table.  I know how to do this already but was hoping for a slicker and quicker (one click) solution.
I did manage to export the data to excel and use a loop to import the data into the oracle table but it was taking far too long to got through the 70k+ rows so will revert to the sql loader.